# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 "The user authentication failed!", ADFS kerberosmixed returns no response

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013, adfs

I'm using the CRM SDK to talk to CRM.

My employer has 2 CRM installations, one in Australia and one in the US. Both installations use the same (Australian) Active Directory domain. The US CRM has a separate ADFS installation.

I've got my application working against the Australian CRM instance, but when I try to run it against the US instance I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException    {"The user authentication failed!"}

I broke out Fiddler and took a look at the traffic: [image: FiddlerTraffic]

The failed request to kerberosmixed seems to be the culprit, it's very strange that no response is returned at all.

I'm curious as to whether this is a problem that I can work around in code, or if this is an issue with the configuration of ADFS that I'll need to talk to the administrators about.

Thanks,

YM

Comment: If you have alternate url  dns names or internal machine names or IP addresses for the "USA" server you may try them from domain and non domain PC's.    This might show you that the USA endpoints work in other scenarios and that will help you nail it down.

Comment: In addition to the first comment, can you confirm that you can login with the same user on the USA server CRM through a browser, from a domain and a non domain PC, considering you are using the same AD for both? Just to confirm that the AD is working correctly on the USA server. Sharing your connection string would be helpful as well.

Comment: I can log in using a browser just fine. I'm not using a connection string. I still don't know how to fix this problem but I found a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround I used UserName authentication instead of Windows authentication. This works perfectly.

Comment: Hi, same problem here. Can you elaborate on this answer? Does it mean you hardcoded the user credentials instead of using `DefaultNetworkCredentials`? Thanks.

Comment: I can't really remember, but I think I made it read in username and password from a config file and use them to log in to CRM instead of using the ADFS based login.

Comment: Thanks. It works indeed that way. Matter of fact, you have to set the `UserName` property instead of `Windows` in `ClientCredentials`, just like you had written.